# Why lowercase uuid?

Tags: swift, uuid

I’m considering using uuid to differentiate my swift app, and looked around online for how to achieve it. While searching, I often found people lowercase the uuid such as:

```
let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString.lowercaseString
```

Wouldn’t lowercasing the uuid be unnecessary or make it less random?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is not less random, because UUIDs are not case-sensitive. UUIDs are 128-bit numbers, and in string form they are represented using hexadecimal digits. ‘A’ and ‘a’ are the same digit.

Standards such as [ITU-T X.667](https://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/UUID/uuids.aspx) and [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) require them to be formatted using lower-case letters, but also require parsers to accept upper-case letters.

The `NSUUID` class and `UUID` struct use upper-case letters when formatting. Long ago, someone either got it wrong, or made the decision before the choice of lower-case letters was standardized. Apple won't change it now because doing so could break existing code that relies on the use of upper-case letters.

On Apple platforms, [the UUID formatting code, `unparse.c`, is written in C](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1439.40.11/uuid/uuidsrc/unparse.c.auto.html), and (according to the copyright) was originally written by Theodore T'so in 1996 or 1997. But the code uses upper-case letters because `UUID_UNPARSE_DEFAULT_UPPER` is [defined in `uuid-config.h`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1439.40.11/uuid/uuid-config.h.auto.html).

Comment: This is not correct. The standard is lower case, and Swift should be outputting lower case.

Comment: You're right. It's about time I cleaned up this answer.

Answer (score 11):

Because it is required by international standards

[You may find the information here](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.667/en)

6.5.4 Software generating the hexadecimal representation of a UUID shall not use upper case letters.
NOTE – It is recommended that the hexadecimal representation used in all human-readable formats be restricted to lower-case
letters.

Comment: There's some extra text at the end of this item: 

6.5.4 Software generating the hexadecimal representation of a UUID shall not use upper case letters.

NOTE – It is recommended that the hexadecimal representation used in all human-readable formats be restricted to lower-case
letters. Software processing this representation is, however, required to accept both upper and lower case letters as specified
in 6.5.2.

Comment: @AlfEaton thats not an excuse though. Just because I should be able to read any case, Swift should not be outputting upper case.

Answer (score -3):

The naming conventions for variable names are to be lower case (even for acronyms):

> - using uppercase for types (and protocols), lowercase for everything else

Here is a Swift programming style guide for reference:
https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

It also refers to the following Swift API Design guide:
https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

Comment: OP is talking about lowercasing the UUID itself, not the variable that holds it.

Comment: Indeed - there you go :)